# encode video from sequence of raw images

Tags: android, c++, image, video

I capture the images while a video is playing in my android phone and keep them in a queue as a raw data (which contains only 0's and 1's). Now i want to convert this raw data of images to video without compressing them to any other formats like PNG or JPEG.I want to do it in android C++. Can any one suggest me how can I do that. Below is my code for capture images.

```
void const* ptr = 0;
uint32_t w, s, h, f;
size_t size = 0;


for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{

  ScreenshotClient screenshot;     
  sp<IBinder> display =    SurfaceComposerClient::getBuiltInDisplay(ISurfaceComposer::eDisplayIdMain);
  if (display != NULL && screenshot.update(display) == NO_ERROR) 
  {
    ptr = screenshot.getPixels();      
    w = screenshot.getWidth();
    h = screenshot.getHeight();
    s = screenshot.getStride();
    f = screenshot.getFormat();
    size = screenshot.getSize();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any library for merging images ?

Comment: This link will help you: http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.com/2011/12/animation-drawbles-in-android.html

Comment: @  Arslan Ahmad, I am not using any library for merging. But I want to take 5 or 10 images at a time stored in the queue.